# HTTPS proxy for debugging frontend without modifying backend

Tags: http, https, http-proxy

I have backend service that is not written by me (so I could not modify it), and I need to implement reaction to some HTTP 400 response. But this response happens very rarely.

How could I implement proxy in node.js or python (or may such thing already exist?) that could select some requests that match pattern, and replace responsce codes for them to defined?

How to make Chrome to talk to the web through that proxy? I'm working from Ubuntu Linux.

Comment: Do you need to automate this in software, or is this just for testing? If you're on Windows, you can use Fiddler to do this for you. If you're on a Mac, then Charles Proxy has a Rewrite Tool. It would be considerably easier than trying to do this yourself. Intercepting HTTPS is a bit of a chore since you need to do certificate generation.

Comment: No, it's Linux, updated my question. But thanks for suggestion, I'll try Charles Proxy, they claim to have Linux version